# c++ double to string shows floating points

Tags: c++, boost, double

I have a string: (66)

Then I convert it to double and do some math: `atof(t.c_str()) / 30`

then I convert it back to string: `string s = boost::lexical_cast<string>(hizdegerd)`

Problem is when I show it on label it becomes 2,20000001.

I've tried everything. sprintf etc.

I want to show only one digit after point.

```
hizdegerd = atof(t.c_str()) / 30;
char buffer [50];
hizdegerd=sprintf (buffer, "%2.2f",hizdegerd);
if(oncekideger != hizdegerd)
{

    txtOyunHiz->SetValue(hizdegerd);

    oncekideger = hizdegerd;
}
```

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Today is the day of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Even reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) might help.

Comment: Also, you overwrite the value in `hizdegerd` when you do that `sprintf`. The `sprintf` function returns the number of characters "printed".

Comment: If it returns printed numbers i can use substring not to show irrelevant numbers. It will works.

edit: It works :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd wrap the formatting up into a function template, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

template <class T>
std::string fmt(T in, int width = 0, int prec = 0) {
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << std::setw(width) << std::setprecision(prec) << in;
    return s.str();
}

int main(){
    std::string s = fmt(66.0 / 30.0, 2, 2);
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way of conversion back to `string` and then only the wished number of digits for the precision will be taken in consideration:

```
ostringstream a;
a.precision(x); // the number of precision digits will be x-1
double b = 1.45612356;
a << b;
std::string s = a.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote "I want to **show**":

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << 34.2356457;
}
```

Output:

```
34.2
```

By the way, sprintf is buffer-overflow-vulnerable and is not C++ .

Comment: Um, `sprintf` is most definitely C++, even if you don't approve of it.

Comment: Yes. Why would you think otherwise?